# How to find Kendo ui previsous documents?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am using old version (2018.3.1017) of Kendo ui. So current version has many changes. But I want to get documents or usage or demos of this version.

For example, https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index has current version examples. How can I find documentation of 2018?

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to use a web archiver to look at old version of the page, like [archive.org](https://archive.org).

Here's the relevant page for your example:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180601000000*/https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

You get a calendar in which you can go to a specific year and see the dates on which the page was archived and view one of those archives. Since you're using 2018.3.1017, I guess you can check out the archive that was done on March 9th or April 3rd, 2018, since I don't know when this version was released and when the documentation was updated.

Comment: the link https://web.archive.org/web/20171121061601/http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export does not contain sapmles.